# mongoose - Delete element by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I am trying to delete a specific property by passing the id of the property, however, the delete removes the first property in the database and not the specific one.

**Server.js**

```
app.delete('/deleteProperty/:id', function(req,res) {
  Property.findOneAndRemove(req.params.propertyId,req.body, function(err,data) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("Deleted");
      }
  });
});
```

**api.service.ts**

```
deleteProperty(id:number) {
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/deleteProperty/'+id)
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**propertyDetail.component.ts**

```
deleteProperty(id)
    {
        this.apiService.deleteProperty(id)
        .subscribe( res => {
           //        this._router.navigate(['/properties']);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
        )
    }
```

**Button in html**

```
<a style="float:right"  color="warn" mat-raised-button (click)="deleteProperty(property.propertyId)">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using `findOneAndRemove` you need to wrap first parameter like this:

```
Property.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.propertyId}, req.body, function(err,data)
{
    if(!err){
        console.log("Deleted");
    }
});
```

If you try method `findByIdAndRemove` then you can call it like you did:

```
Property.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.propertyId,req.body, function(err,data)
{
    if(!err){
        console.log("Deleted");
    }
});
```

More information you can find in [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove).

Comment: I was going nuts because I had a list of items and every time I clicked on a selected item, the above one was deleted instead. I thought it was a front-end issue... I was not specifying the field for the query and this returned other ID. This solution detail solved the issue finally.